# file_get_contents() works when called from browser but not curl

Tags: php, apache, cgi-bin

I have a php script that kicks off a process in a cgi program.

If I hit the script from a browser `https://mysite/myscript.php`,

it will call `https:/mysite/cgi-bin/mycgi` just fine

If I call `https://mysite/myscript.php` from my Linux server prompt with curl

`curl -k https://mysite/myscript.php`

I get "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error"

I have tried setting the user agent using  -A"Mozilla/5.0" for example with no luck

Thank you!

Comment: Look at the server logs to se what's causing the server error, then fix that.

Comment: checking the log I see
    **Premature end of script headers: mycgi**
I guess I should start debugging the cgi
thank you

Comment: Here I was looking for some hidden difference in the functionality and it was my problem all along....as is generally the case.  my cgi application was not correctly handling a mysql call.
Your comment led directly to the solution, but I do not see a way to mark the comment as the answer.